# Python replace 1.0 and 0.0 with True and False in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a big data frame. I want to replace float 1.0 and 0.0 with true and false.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0]})
df.replace(1.0,True,inplace=True).replace(0.0,False,inplace=True)
```

Present output:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

If I do it separately in two lines, it will work. I want to do it in one line.

Comment: `map` with `{1: True, 0: False}`. `.astype(bool)` is good, though can be dangerous as `bool(np.NaN)` is `True` as well as `bool('foo')`, for instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with `bool` :-)

```
df.A=df.A.astype(bool)
df
Out[69]: 
       A
0   True
1  False
2   True
3  False
```

Comment: Thanks again. I did not know this that it is this simple. :-) Happy coding.